# best value for fps in createVideoWriter() openCV

Tags: opencv, frame-rate

I have this camera application that I'm working on which uses openCV for image processing. I was wondering what is the best value of 'fps' for createVideoWriter() so that the video is closest to the real world timeframe!!

Regards, Aayush Shrestha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 should be enough. 25 if you need a smaller video.

Answer (score 0):

25 is the best value but unfortunately, it is difficult toa achieve if you are taking input from a cheap webcam

Answer (score 0):

If you read your images from video file, process and save to file then use the same fps as in input file. Otherwise the result will look bad (too fast or too slow).

If you read from camera and process in real-time use the same frame rate of your camera. Should be 25-30 but for medium cameras it is 15 and for very cheap it might be even 10.
Use 25 to be on the safe side.

If you create artificial video and save to file then my advise would be to use such frame rate that the fastes motion will not be more then half image in a second. For example if you create movie of bouncing ball - it moves 20 pixels each frame and your video width is 640 pixels then the maximal frame rate would be 16. Otherwise spectators would become dizzy due to fast motions.